# Stop javascript audio when popup loads

Tags: javascript, audio, video

This is the page in question:

```
http://49.156.27.50/~dmg/index-members.php#!the-fun-begins.html
```

This site automatically plays audio when the page loads. On that same page is a link to a video that loads as a popup (grey box at the bottom). I need the audio to pause or stop while the video is playing.

I am using Soundmanager2 to play the audio:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
soundManager.play('more-than-a-room');
</script>
```

To stop the audio when a new page loads I am using this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
soundManager.stopAll();
</script>
```

So is there a way to pause or stop the audio when the user clicks the popup link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using jquery too :

```
$('#theidofyourlink').on("click", function(event){
    soundManager.stopAll();
});
```

or if you are just using simple javascript add an onclick event to your a href element

```
<a href="..." onclick="soundManager.stopAll();">
```